# Joining points to a single point

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis, spatial-query

I am using postgres with postgis for spatial data. I have a table containing a set of points of intersections, the one below is the structure of the table;

[image]

Each point represent an intersection between two roads. BUT I have some roads where three roads meet rather than two and for that, 3 distinct points are being created. The following image shows the issue;

[image]

I would like to collect three distinct points into just one point and that point would represent the intersection of all the three roads rather than having three distinct roads.

I was thinking of using the st_collect and st_convexhull and than st_centroid to find a single point from the points. BUT  i can notmake it work, probably I am taking the wrong approach.

How is best to tackle such problem?

Answer (score 1):

This here example shows how to calculate centroid point from 3 points, without using st_convexhull, I am not sure I understand why you want to use convexhull.

```
with mypoints as (
    select 1 id, 1 cat, ST_MakePoint(5, 5) geom
    union all
    select 2 id, 1 cat, ST_MakePoint(5, 10) geom
    union all
    select 3 id, 1 cat, ST_MakePoint(8, 8) geom
)
select st_astext(st_centroid(st_collect(geom))) from mypoints group by cat;
```